# TypeError: tslib.__spreadArrays is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, tslib

I am getting the following error in the browser in Ionic 3 when doing `ionic serve`.

```
TypeError: tslib.__spreadArrays is not a function
```

This is happening after I downgraded to `"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3"` from `"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4"` because of another error.

Answer (score 7):

I am getting the same error, but using 3.2.4, so my guess is that it is another problem

I upgraded to tslib 1.10 and the error went away (Giving me the next issue to fix)

Comment: Yes, when `npm i tslib@latest` error goes away.